# Which type of router is capable of torrents download restrictions?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, bittorrent, qos

At rented room, we've got shared VDSL internet for around 20 people.

However, some idiot is downloading torrents and he's sucking up all the downstream bandwidth. I suggested the renter to buy a new router which can restrict torrents usage.

I don't know what exactly am I looking for, but I know it's possible, because at home, our ISP(optical net) somehow restricts torrents downloading. I would like to configure similar thing here for the renter. However, I would like to know which type of router is capable of such restrictions.

Comment: `Questions seeking for hardware shopping recommendations are off-topic because they are often relevant only to the question author at the time the question was asked and tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead of asking what to buy, try asking how to find out what suits your needs`

Comment: I'm not asking which router,... but which type of router / what functionality router must provide... I'm asking about restriction of torrents and how it's possible,... :)

Comment: Are you sure its the download bandwidth that is being saturated and not the number of simultanous connections the router can handle and uploads?     When I ran an ISP back in the dark ages we used Linux and pooled data - effectively QoS - so a router running Linux like dd-wrt, openwrt, Tomato should help.  I'm somewhat skeptical about @Spiff recommendations on bufferbloat, but he could be right as well.  I imagine that if your latencies are high and you have a decent speed connection you need to look at bufferbloat, if you are getting significant packet loss you need to look at QoS.

Comment: I ran 8 speed tests in parallel, and ping together. Average ping was 1200ms and 10% packet loss. So, is it buffer bloat?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to throttle Torrents. You're probably experiencing bufferbloat-caused latency spikes. Fix your bufferbloat problem and the symptoms you're noticing will probably go away.

Any router that can take a recent version of OpenWrt (and probably DD-WRT as well, and maybe Tomato) can be configured to use the fq_codel smart queue management algorithm and ECN (Explicit Congestion Notification) to defeat bufferbloat.

For more information, see [bufferbloat.net's introduction to the problem](http://www.bufferbloat.net/projects/bloat/wiki/Introduction/).